# я увеличил размер шрифта в pycharm, и теперь не могу убрать

Tags: python, pycharm, macos

[image]

поставил нечаянно 72 px, комбинации клавиш не работают, command + mouse тоже
и интерфейс самого pycharm только первая половина

Comment: у вас jetbrains-ide ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39216427/how-to-increase-menu-and-tab-font-size-in-intellij-jetbrains-pycharm-phpstorm может тут найдете ответ?

Comment: уже откатил через restore settings